# Flask render_template() does not work when request is sent using the Fetch API

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I have a background task that handles a long running computation. I use Redis and RQ to update a progress bar. When the background task completes, I trigger my app (from Javascript) to render a page with the results of my background task by sending a request to the app using the Fetch API.

My route gets executed (I can set a breakpoint and step through my code, verifying everything works correctly). However, when I return render_template() at the end of the route, nothing happens.

If I print out the request prior to render template and then click on the URL, it renders correctly. I suspect there is something wrong with the request that is generated by Fetch. Below is my Javascript code that uses fetch(). Note that I used the same "content-type" as the request that worked from clicking the URL.

```
fetch(`/scenario/` + job_id + `/display_result`, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
          },
        })
```

Comment: And what do you do of the result if that fetch ? for now we see nothing of that king. If you do not display the request result yes "nothing happens"

Comment: @azro, sorry, but I'm very new to this. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: You ask the server for some content, then you need to use it and display it in the page, it not it'll just be lost

Answer (score 1):

I missed to use the request response and display it in my page, here is the final code:

```
fetch(`/scenario/` + job_id + `/display_result`, {
          method: "GET",
}).then((response) => {
    return response.text();
}).then((html) => {
    document.body.innerHTML = html
});
```